# Errno::EINVAL Invalid argument @ io_fread

Tags: ruby

I'm attempting to download a ~2GB file and write it to a file locally but I'm running into this issue:

[image]

Here's the applicable code:

```
  File.open(local_file, "wb") do |tempfile|
    puts "Downloading the backup..."

    pbar = nil
    open(backup_url,
         :read_timeout => nil,
         :content_length_proc => lambda do |content_length|
           if content_length&.positive?
             pbar = ProgressBar.create(:total => content_length)
           end
         end,
         :progress_proc => ->(size) { pbar&.progress = size }) do |retrieved|
          begin
            tempfile.binmode
            tempfile << retrieved.read
            tempfile.close
          rescue Exception => e
            binding.pry
          end
    end
```

Comment: It could be your connection is being killed before the download can complete, or there was a problem retrieving the file. Can you test with smaller files to verify this works?

Comment: @tadman definitely works with smaller files

Comment: Is there some kind of firewall that terminates large downloads? Are you possibly running out of memory? For example, can you pull it down with `curl` or `wget` via command-line?

Comment: Why do you specify lambdas in two different ways? `lambda do |content_length|` and `->(size) { ... }`? Where is `tempfile` set? What is `backup_url`? Some servers have a max connection time, like 15-30s. When copying large files, it's best to go low level and use buffers like 1M for each chunk. The standard libraries may try to read the entire file into memory. You may have to use HTTP ranges to get parts of the file in pieces. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Range_requests

Answer (score 3):

### Read your file in chunks.

The line causing the issue is here:

`tempfile << retrieved.read`

This reads the entire contents into memory before writing it to the `tempfile`. If the content is small, this isn't a big deal, but if this content is quite large (how large depends on the system, configuration, OS and available resources), this can cause an `Errno::EINVAL` error, like `Invalid argument @ io_fread` and `Invalid argument @ io_write`.

To work around this, read the content in chunks and write each chunk to the `tempfile`. Something like this:

```rb
tempfile.write( retrieved.read( 1024 ) ) until retrieved.eof?
```

This will get chunks of `1024` bytes and write each chunk to the `tempfile` until `retrieved` reaches the end of the file (i.e. `.eof?`).

If `retrieved.read` doesn't take a size parameter, you may need to convert `retrieved` into a `StringIO`, like this:

```rb
retrievedIO = StringIO.new( retrieved )
tempfile.write( retrievedIO.read( 1024 ) ) until retrievedIO.eof?
```